# Issue with Ember's loading substates

Tags: javascript, web, ember.js

My application has a common loading Ux where during loading I want a majority of my routes to do one thing, show a spinner. To accomplish this, I dropped that behavior all the way down to the ApplicationRoute by overriding the loading method:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
       loading: function() {
           console.log("Show loading spinner");
           return true;
       }
   } 
});
```

However, one of my nested routes I want to do something more custom and not show the spinner, but instead use a custom template.  I expected to override loading at that nested level and not bubble up the loading message up to ApplicationRoute, but this has the adverse effect of not rendering my template. If I bubble up, then I see my template AND I see a loading spinner.

A JS-fiddle highlighting the issue is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ssirowy/P8azn/4/

Where is my approach wrong here?  Should I just implement 'loading' in all of my routes and call a loadSpinner method with the exception of my interested nested route? Any other approaches?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So after struggling with this for a bit, I ended up implementing the above differently. Instead of catching all routes in ApplicationRoute and displaying the spinner, I implemented a basic method off the ApplicationController called showSpinner, and then all routes that want to show that spinner must opt in by implementing loading and calling that showSpinner method.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    //... other functionality

    // Methods to show a spinner in main body of app
    showSpinner: function() {
        console.log('SPINNER!');
    }
};
```

Because I had several routes that implemented this exact loading behavior and nothing else, I created a simple mixin for showing the spinner that overrides the loading method:

```
App.ShowSpinner = Ember.Mixin.create({
    actions: {
        loading: function(transition, originRoute) {
           this.controllerFor('application').showSpinner();
           return true;
        }
    }
});
```

and take advantage of it by doing this:

```
App.RouteThatWantsSpinner = Ember.Route.extend(App.ShowSpinner, {
    model: function() {
        return something;
    }
});
```

Another answer that is more in line with the original question would be great, but this solution works for me now